# compare files where 2 columns of csv file do not match

Tags: awk

I have this awk command that is working as expected.

```
awk -F';' '          # delimiter
NR==FNR {             # process the stem file
    gsub(/"/,"")      # off with the double quotes
    a[$2]=$1          # hash
    next
}
{
    if($1 in a)       # if corpus entry found in stem
        print "XXX"   # output
    else
        print $1
}' stem.txt corpus.txt
```

Returns:

```
this
is
XXX
XXX
as
XXX
XXX
```

But I want the output to include the word 'test' and the expected results are:

```
this
is
XXX
XXX
as
test
XXX
```

This is because "test" is the same in column 1 and column 2 in the stem file.

```
# cat stem.txt
"test";"tested";"test";"Suffix";"A";"7673";"321: 0 xxx"
"test";"testing";"test";"Suffix";"A";"7673";"322: 0 xxx"
"test";"test";"test";"Suffix";"b";"5942";"001: 0 xxx"
"break";"broke";"break";"Suffix";"b";"5942";"002: 0 xxx"
"break";"broken";"break";"Suffix";"b";"5942";"003: 0 xxx"
"break";"breaks";"break";"Suffix";"c";"5778";"001: 0 xxx"
"tell";"told";"tell";"Suffix";"c";"5778";"002: 0 xx"
```

Only the records where column1 and column2 do not match will qualify to be compared with corpus file.

```
# cat corpus.txt
this
is
broken
testing
as
test
told
```

I tried to modify the if clause, but that does not seem to work

```
if($1 in a && a[$1] == a[$2])
```

Comment: Your expected output is not clear(not syncing to your shown samples), could you please elaborate why `testing` is there in output on 4th line where 1st field(`"break"`), 2nd field(`"broke"`) are not same?(not my downvote btw), thank you.

Comment: If you remove the 3rd line from stem file and run my command, you will get the expected output. The reason to remove only 3rd line is that the first and second column text is the same. Both the files are large and may contain unicode text and therefore grep and python tags were not added.

Comment: I got that logic but whey 4th line is not having testing in your output? Because its 1st and 2nd fields are different and it should print `testing` as per your shown logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=";"
}
{
  gsub(/"/,"")
}
FNR==NR{
  if($1!=$2){ arr[$2] }
  next
}
{
  print ($0 in arr)?"XXX":$0
}' stem.txt corpus.txt
```

With shown samples output will be as follows:

```
this
is
XXX
XXX
as
test
XXX
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                            ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                           ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  FS=OFS=";"                     ##Setting field and output field separators to ; here.
}
{
  gsub(/"/,"")                   ##Globally substituting ; to NULL here.
}
FNR==NR{                         ##Checking condition which will be TRUE when stem.txt is being read.
  if($1!=$2){ arr[$2] }          ##Checking if 1st and 2nd fields are NOT equal then set arr index as $2.
  next                           ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  print ($0 in arr)?"XXX":$0     ##Printing XXX is current line present in arr else print current line.
}' stem.txt corpus.txt           ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: This does not return the expected output.

Comment: @shantanuo, your 4th line's 1st and 2nd field are NOT equal `"break";"broke"` then why testing is not printed there? Please elaborate on that part.

Comment: Corpus file line 1 should not compared with stem file line 1. It should be compared with all lines in stem file.

Comment: @shantanuo, Please do check my edited code, that should work for you, thank you. Let me know ho it goes.

Comment: This does not return the expected output: test break tell XXX XXX XXX XXX

Comment: @shantanuo, I am sorry your Logic is still not clear. could you please elaborate it here more. You want to compare 1st and 2nd fields of stem.txt file and then compare it(not sure which field?) to whole file stem.txt? Kindly do let me know on same.

Comment: Compare the text of corpus file with the second column of stem file provided the first and second column of stem file is not equal. If the match is found then 'XXX' else print the text of corpus file. Maintaining order is preferred for auditing.

Comment: @shantanuo, sure edited answer and its giving same output as per shown samples.